# Non-'@objc' method 'didFinish' does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'YPSignatureDelegate'

Tags: swift

We are using YPDrawSignature from here to draw a signature on the IOS App.

We are getting the following error on the UIViewController.

```
Non-'@objc' method 'didFinish' does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'YPSignatureDelegate'

The UIViewController is this.

class SignatureViewController:  UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, YPSignatureDelegate {
    func didStart(_ view : YPDrawSignatureView) {
       // print("Started Drawing")
    }

    func didFinish(_ view : YPDrawSignatureView){
      // func didFinish (){
     }

}
```

UPDATE.

We tried the following.

```
@objc func didStart(_view : YPDrawSignatureView) {
    // print("Started Drawing")
}
```

But still get the same error.

The YPDrawSignatureView has the following Delegate

```
@objc
public protocol YPSignatureDelegate: class {
   func didStart(_ view : YPDrawSignatureView)
   func didFinish(_ view : YPDrawSignatureView)

}


extension YPSignatureDelegate {

   func didStart(_ view : YPDrawSignatureView) {}
   func didFinish(_ view : YPDrawSignatureView) {}

 }
```

Comment: Simply add `@objc` to `functionalists didFinish` inside `SignatureViewController`

Comment: We tried that. But still get the same error.

Comment: Remove the blank protocol implementation. ObjectiveC doesn’t support that.

Comment: @WarrenBurton Can you please elaborate? I am not following you.

Comment: The code in `extension YPDrawSignature` . Comment that out. Objective C doesn’t support default implementation.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I meant try removing the code in `extension YPSignatureDelegate`

Comment: @objc func didStart(_view : YPDrawSignatureView) {
    // print("Started Drawing")
}

This is wrong, you need a space between _ and view:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've downloaded YPSignatureView, and did similar to what you have. All I implemented was:

```
func didStart(_ view : YPDrawSignatureView) {}
func didFinish(_ view : YPDrawSignatureView) {}
```

and of-coarse assigning a delegate to the view, with those methods implemented by the delegate. And I don't get any errors. **Make sure you haven't accidentally changed the YPSignatureView.swift file by clicking on the red button that says `Fix` as a suggestion**. Before I implemented didStart and didFinish, I did get the same error as you have, with a button that says `Fix in YPSignatureView`. Clicking on that silently changes code within YPSignatureView.swift. Make sure YPSignatureView.swift is pristine and implement the above two functions and you should be fine. Re-download the file to be safe, implement those two methods as above, and thats it.

My didStart() and didFinish() functions are called when touches begins and finishes respectively. Let me know how you go.

Update: as mentioned above, you probably clicked on these two error messages here:

[image]

Do not do that. If you did then get a fresh copy of that file then just implement the protocol methods without any `@objc`. Hit `Command + Shift + k` to clean build folder and then build again. I did not get any errors after that, runs fine, and yours should too.

Answer (score 2):

In your implementation, you forgot to put the space between `_` and `view`;

Change

`func didFinish(_view : YPDrawSignatureView)` to

`func didFinish(_ view : YPDrawSignatureView)`